# When should I use the new ranged-for and can I combine it with the new cbegin/cend?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, foreach, idioms

The new **ranged-for** in C++11 will be very concise and useful, of course. As far as I understand how it works, it looks up the "containers" **`begin` and `end`** by trying *Argument-Depending-Lookup" (ADT).

But another addition is that all the containers **now have `cbegin()` and `cend()`** to get the `const_iterators` for the container.

I am a bit confused, on the one hand I guess I should use `cbegin()` if I do *not* want to modify the container, on the other hand I have to add an additional `const` inside the *ranged-for* to get the same thing.

So, it looks like this:

```
// print all
for(const auto elem : data)
  cout << elem
```

using ADT, finding data.begin(), thus `const` needed.

vs

```
// print everything but the first (a reason not to use range-for)
for(auto it = data.cbegin()+1; it!=data.cend(); ++it)
  cout << *it
```

using `data.cbegin()`, thus no `const` needed.

But would this not be more "idiomatic"?:

```
// print everything but the first (a reason not to use range-for)
for(const auto it = data.begin()+1; it!=data.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it
```

- Did I get the "idiom" right? Any additions?
- When should I use `cbegin`?
- Do I miss something with ranged-for, looking for `begin()` only?

**Edit:** correction of error *Value vs Iterator*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cbegin()` allows you to get `const_iterator`s from a non-`const` container without an explicit cast or conversion. If you have a `const` container then `begin()` will return a `const_iterator` anyway.

The new `for` construct uses `begin()` because that's the most general, and it avoids too many special cases. Also, by default, the variable is a **value**, not an iterator or a reference.

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(auto i: v) // i is an int
    dostuff(i);
```

This avoids the problem of modifying the container, as the element is copied. To get a reference you need to declare it:

```
for(auto &i: v)
    dostuff(i);
```

Comment: Yes. So for a *non-const* container `v` `const auto it1 = v.begin()` the **not** the same as `auto it2 = v.cbegin()`? The first is `const iterator it`, the second `const_iterator it`. Those are distinct types, and I can *not* do `++it1`, because the iterator itself is `const`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use cbegin/cend in in the `for` loop if the intention is not to modify the elements in the range. That's the obvious reason for adding them in the first place.

This is hardly idiomatic yet, as the new standard isn't even off the presses!