# forcing use of cbegin()/cend() in range-based for

Tags: c++

This question refers to:

[When should I use the new ranged-for and can I combine it with the new cbegin/cend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814553/ranged-for-and-cbegin-cend/5815268#5815268)

Based on that question, to force the use of `cbegin()` and `cend()`, one needs to do, for example:

```
for (auto& v: const_cast<decltype(container) const>(container))
```

That's a lot of boilerplate code for a construct that was supposed to eliminate it. Is there some more compact way to do it? The reason for my question is, that an implicitly shared container might take my use of `begin()` as a clue to detach itself.

Comment: The ranged for loop was added for convenience, not as a replacement for the existing for-statement. Perhaps this is one case where the old for loop is more useful?

Comment: You probably want `decltype((container))` to get a reference.

Comment: You know, you could just type `const auto &v`.

Comment: @NicolBolas AFAIK that's not enough. Sure, you won't be able to modify `v`, but the container and the iterators won't be `const` for it.

Comment: @user1095108: Is that really important? The container isn't const in your version either, as the non-`const` `container` must still be accessible within the loop. So if you wanted to change it, you can. As for the iterators, you can't access them. So it doesn't matter that they're not `const_iterator`s. So it's not like you can break things in some way.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want it to be `const &` (there might be a bug somewhere though). Calling `begin()` on a `const` qualified container will forward to `cbegin()` and will return a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @user1095108: But there's no *functional* difference if you make the `auto&` `const`. Well, except if `T` happens to be a pointer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Update: [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) will be in C++17, in the `<utility>` header.

*Prior to C++17*, there's no built-in syntax for it; however, you can easily write a convenience wrapper:

```
template<typename T> constexpr const T &as_const(T &t) noexcept { return t; }
for (auto &v: as_const(container))
```

Note that this calls `begin() const` rather than `cbegin()` specifically; the [Standard container general requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general) specify that `cbegin()` and `begin() const` behave identically.

If your container treats non-const iteration specially, it might make sense for it itself to have a member function:

```
const Container &crange() const noexcept { return *this; }
for (auto &v: container.crange())
```

Comment: I think you should have prepended the `constexpr` specifier to your `as_const()` trick.

Comment: @user1095108, why would one need `constexpr` there? Container's content may change.

Comment: @Yola `constexpr` means that it can be used within constant expressions, it doesn't mean that it can't change.

Comment: Have you tested this? The const overload of `begin` is called, but not `cbegin` in my case. See http://cpp.sh/7yr3

Comment: @mbschenkel `cbegin()` should behave identically to `begin() const`. See **[container.requirements.general]**: http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general.

Comment: Based on the question, I read your answer such that `for(auto const T& ...)` would call `cbegin`, but it actually calls the `const` overload of `begin`. You show how to enforce this, but it is not obvious that `cbegin` is never called from a range-based `for` loop.

Comment: @mbschenkel it's a largely irrelevant distinction, given that any container treating `cbegin()` differently to `begin() const` is defective. It's reasonable to use `cbegin` as a shorthand for `begin() const`.

Comment: @ectamur: Agreed, according to the standard `cbegin()` and `begin() const` shall behave equally. But the standard does not guarantee that the compiler has to search for `cbegin()` after it has failed to find `begin() const`. This is what g++ 7.2 does. I feel that you _must_ implement both methods.

Comment: @hermannk certainly a container that provides `cbegin()` but does not provide `begin() const` would be defective, so there's not much point searching for the former if the latter is not present. I agree that a well-written container should provide both.

Answer (score 19):

The range-based for loop never uses `cbegin()` or `cend()`. (Therefore there is no way to force it.) There are surprisingly many rumors to the contrary; some believe that `cbegin()` and `cend()` are used, but never try whether the same code would compile without `begin()` and `end()`. A trivial example follows. Presumably, only `begin` and `end` will be printed out, no matter how many `const_cast`s are added.

```
#include <iostream>

class Iterable {
  struct Iterator {
    bool operator !=(const Iterator &) { return false; }
    int operator *(){ return 0; }
    Iterator& operator ++() { return *this; }
  };
public:
  Iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
    std::cout << "cbegin" << std::endl;
    return Iterator{};
  }
  Iterator cend() const noexcept {
    std::cout << "cend" << std::endl;
    return Iterator{};
  }
  Iterator begin() const noexcept {
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
    return Iterator{};
  }
  Iterator end() const noexcept {
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    return Iterator{};
  }
};

int main() {
  Iterable a;
  const Iterable b;
  for (auto i : a) {}
  for (auto i : b) {}
  for (const auto &i : a) {}
  for (const auto &i : b) {}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: many (all) are knowledgeable enough to know that a call to .`begin()` on a const container is equivalent to calling `cbegin()`

Comment: No, it is not. Simply because you are free to provide an implementation of `cbegin()` completely different form `begin()` if you so decide. The key point of my answer: The original question is based on a wrong assumption that the range-based `for` loop calls `cbegin()` or `cend()` under certain conditions. In fact it doesn't. That's all.

Comment: It usually does the equivalent thing, of the container is const.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to this OP's question, pointing out that the original question was wrong in the first place.

Comment: The compiler choose the overload `begin() const` for a const container, or `begin()` for a non-const container. And usually, `begin() const` and `cbegin() const` have the same implementation and return a const iterator, while `begin()` returns a non-const iterator. The initial question is almost right, simply it's more explicit to speak about `begin()` vs `cbegin()` than `begin()` vs `begin() const`. I think it's why the standard added these two methods cbegin() and cend() with C++11. But not for the for loops.

Comment: The main point was that while `begin()` and `begin() const` are relevant for range-based `for` loops, `cbegin()` is not (and will never be invoked by a range-based `for`). Personally I never implement `cbegin()`, because I don’t see a practical use for it. All it brings is confusion, especially when its implementation diverges from `begin() const`.

Answer (score 14):

```
const auto& const_container = container;

for (const auto& v: const_container ) {
```

Comment: Where `Type` is spelled `auto`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I've changed to using `auto` for the container reference, and improved the name a little, too.

Comment: I suggest explicitly const-qualifying `&v` for additional clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Update: there is a simple and correct way in c++23, namely  [`views::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/as_const_view):

```
for (auto&& elem: container | views::as_const)
```

which ensures that the elements of the original container are not modified.