# How to write a unique_ptr whose pointer and data is const

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The first time I tried to write a range based for loop to iterate over unique_ptrs I wrote:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec;
// Initialize vec

for (auto v : vec) // error
{}
```

I then realized this is trying to create a copy of each element which doesn't make sense with a unique_ptr.  So then I wrote it as a reference:

```
for (auto& v : vec)
{}
```

Adding a const in front of it keeps me from changing the pointer.

```
for (const auto& v : vec)
{
   v = nullptr; // error (good!)
}
```

How can I write it, so that the data pointed to cannot be changed?  For example, the following code should not compile.

```
for (??? v : vec)
{
   v->func();
}

class Foo
{
public:
   void func();

private:
   bool mBar;
}

Foo::func()
{
   mbar = true; // Should cause error
}
```

Comment: Do you always need the pointee to be `const` (and thus can alter the definition of `vec`) or do you only need it to be `const` *for this loop* ?

Comment: Another application of this could be writing an inspector function, so preferably for only the loop.  However, from the answers this doesn't sound possible.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518894/forcing-use-of-cbegin-cend-in-range-based-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent the data from being modified, include `const` in the template parameter for your pointer:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Foo>> vec;
```

I think you'll have problems making the pointer itself `const` though. The reason is that the vector has to be able to copy the pointer object around internally (e.g. when the container is resized). With a `unique_ptr`, that means ownership has to be transferred between instances, meaning it has to be mutable (not const).

To make the pointer itself `const`, I think you've got two main choices: use a vector of `const shared_ptr<>`, or an array (i.e. fixed size) of `const unique_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 3):

For that, your `unique_pointer` must be instantiated for a `const`-qualified type, like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Foo>> vec;
```

But maybe it is enough to use the iterator to initialise a constant reference at the start of the loop, the compiler should optimise it away:

```
for (const auto& v_iter : vec) {
    const auto& x = *v_iter;
    do_things(...);
}
```

Everything else is hackery.

What probably would work is reinterpreting your `vector<unique_pointer<Foo>>` as a `vector<unique_pointer<const Foo>>`, but it might result in hilarious undefined behavior if either `vector` or `unique_pointer` has a specialisation. **Do not try**, it is not worth that.