# Does deleteLater() of Qt5.7 depend of the operative system?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Good day everyone, I discovered a bug in my code, that is:

I have a list of pointers to QLocalSocket and in the destructor I close and delete them with the following piece of code

```
for ( int i = 0; i < localSocketsList.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( localSocketsList.at(i) != NULL )
    {
        localSocketsList.at(i)->close();
        localSocketsList.at(i)->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

The bug was that I previously connected a slot with the disconnected() signal of the sockets, and the slot delete them as well with the code:

```
QMutableListIterator<QLocalSocket *> iterator(localSocketsList);
while( iterator.hasNext() )
{
    QLocalSocket * currentLocalSocket = iterator.next();
    if ( currentLocalSocket -> state() == QLocalSocket::UnconnectedState )
    {
        currentLocalSocket -> deleteLater();
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Ok right now you can see the error, I try to delete a pointer twice and I have a crash. BUT, it took me a while to detect this error because I did not observe a crash in Windows 10, only in Windows 7.

The question is: is there some difference in the deleteLater() function of Qt5.7 depending of the operative system? Shouldn't this problem appear in all platforms, since it is a c++ run time error?

Maybe is something depending of how Qt schedules the job (I mean, finishing the for cycle before sending the signals)? In that case is the schedule of the jobs depending of the OS? Shouldn't this be almost "random"?

Thanks everybody

Comment: Are you sure it happens in the same event loop cycle? It is OK to call it multiple times IN THE SAME CYCLE, as pending events will be removed, but if it is not the same cycle, you will get a crash, because it is a dangling pointer.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that I could call deleteLater twice in the same cycle. But why in Windows 10 I have no error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid to invoke `deleteLater` multiple times before the control returns to the event loop:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  auto obj = new QObject;
  obj->deleteLater();
  obj->deleteLater();
  connect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, []{ qApp->quit(); });
  return app.exec();
}
```

Thus, it seems to me that your problem isn't in invoking `deleteLater` multiple times, but iterating over a collection of objects that have been destroyed. The `localSocketList` is not aware of the sockets being deleted and contains dangling pointers.

There's a simple remedy for that - use a list that is aware of objects being deleted. For simplicity, the list below is explicitly shared, i.e. any of its copies refer to the same object (those are also JavaScript semantics, if you're familiar with them).

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qobject-pointer-list-43986348
#include <QtCore>

class PointerListData : public QObject, public QSharedData {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   QVector<QObject*> list;
   void removed() { list.removeAll(sender()); }
   void connect(QObject* obj) {
      QObject::connect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, this, &PointerListData::removed);
   }
   void disconnect(QObject* obj) {
      QObject::disconnect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, this, &PointerListData::removed);
   }
};

template <typename T> class PointerList {
protected:
   QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<PointerListData> d;
public:
   PointerList() : d(new PointerListData) {}
   PointerList(const PointerList &other) : d(other.d) {}
   PointerList(PointerList && other) : d(std::move(other.d)) {}
   void append(T* obj) {
      auto connect = !contains(obj);
      d->list.append(obj);
      if (connect)
         d->connect(obj);
   }
   PointerList & operator<<(T* obj) {
      append(obj);
      return *this;
   }
   int removeAll(T* obj) {
      auto n = d->list.removeAll(obj);
      if (n)
         d->disconnect(obj);
      return n;
   }
   bool contains(T* obj) const {
      return d->list.contains(obj);
   }
   void clear() {
      for (auto obj : d->list)
         d->disconnect(obj);
      d->list.clear();
   }

   void moveToThread(QThread* thread) { d->moveToThread(thread); }
   bool isEmpty() const { return d->list.isEmpty(); }
   int size() const { return d->list.size(); }
   using iterator = T**;
   using const_iterator = const T**;
   iterator begin() { return iterator(d->list.data()); }
   iterator end() { return iterator(d->list.data() + d->list.size()); }
   const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(d->list.constData()); }
   const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(d->list.constData() + d->list.size()); }
   constexpr const PointerList& crange() const noexcept { return *this; }
     // see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15518894/1329652
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
   PointerList<QMimeData> list;
   {
      QMimeData a;
      QMimeData b;
      list << &a << &b;
      auto list2 = list;
      Q_ASSERT(list2.size() == 2);
      for (auto obj : list.crange())
         qDebug() << obj;
   }
   Q_ASSERT(list.isEmpty());

}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It make sense what you say, probably the error is the "remove" of the list. But even so, why I did not see this error in Window 10? I discovered it only when I tried Windows 7

Comment: Because your code is asynchronous and the disconnect notification may arrive at a different time. I'm pretty sure that the Windows version only changes the probability of this error occurring - had you tested it enough (millions or even billions of connections), you'd have it occur on any version of Windows.

Comment: Thanks very much ;) Figuring out that the problem was the list and not the double deleteLater() helped me a lot. ;)