# Is cbegin/cend not enough for a range based for loop?

Tags: c++

I have a class, let's call it ConstVector, that only defines cbegin/cend and not begin/end because I don't want to allow modifications to its members after construction. I tried to use the range based for loop like this:

```
ConstVector const_vector(1, 2, 3);
for(const auto &x : const_vector)
....
```

While the relevant part of the class looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class ConstVector
{
    public:
        ConstVector(std::initializer_list<T> values);
        typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator cbegin(void) const;
        typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator cend(void) const;

    private:
        std::vector<T> data;
};

template<class T>
ConstVector::ConstVector(std::initializer_list<T> values)
    : data(values)
{
}

template<class T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator ConstVector<T>::cbegin() const
{
    return this->data.cbegin();
}

template<class T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator ConstVector<T>::cend() const
{
    return this->data.cend();
}
```

But my compiler complains:

```
‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
```

My question is: Do I have to implement begin/end? As far as I understood it, it should choose cbegin/cend if it's `const auto &x` and not `auto &x`. At least that's what would make sense to me. If I remove my range based for loop, everything compiles fine.

I also tried pretty much everything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15518894/7421666) to make it `const`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do I have to implement begin/end?

Yes.

> As far as I understood it, it should choose `cbegin/cend` if it's `const auto &x` and not `auto &x`.

That's not how the range-based `for` is defined in the standard. Range-based `for` always looks for `begin()` and `end()`. From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/stmt.ranged.

> otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up with argument-dependent lookup ([basic.lookup.argdep]). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace std is an associated namespace.