# Using for_each on container with const_iterators?

Tags: c++, foreach, containers

If you iterate on an std container with this elegant formula:

```
for (auto& item: queue) {}
```

It will be using queue's `begin` and `end` functions.

Is there a way to use `cbegin` and `cend` without modifying the queue's source?

I tried with

```
for (const auto& item: queue) {}
```

But if `begin` or `end` is missing, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Reated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15518894, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44332074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use cbegin and cend without modifying the queue's
> source?

In C++20, you can use `queue.cbegin()` and `queue.cend()` to construct a [`ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange):

```
#include <ranges>

for (auto& item: std::ranges::subrange(queue.cbegin(), queue.cend())) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `for (auto& item : std::as_const(queue)) {}`. It still calls `begin()` but it’s `const` so it picks the const overload.