# C++ iterating over a class that wraps around a list

Tags: c++, iterator, stdlist

Sorry for such a bad title but I don't know how to condense what I want to say. Anyway, I have a template class that wraps around a list, something simple like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyWrapper {
    std::list<T> items;
}
```

I want to be able to use this wrapper in a foreach loop. As my class is simply wrapping a list (i.e. it's not really a custom collection), I think I can just use that list's iterator functions as my own:

```
typename _Container::iterator begin () noexcept {
    return items.begin();
}

typename _Container::iterator end () noexcept {
    return items.end();
}

typename _Container::const_iterator cbegin () const noexcept {
    return items.cbegin();
}

typename _Container::const_iterator cend () const noexcept {
    return items.cend();
}
```

This works fine for non-const instantiations of my class, but not for const-ones. Example:

```
// this one works fine and iterates the inner list as you'd expect.
MyWrapper& mywr = someMethod(); // returns MyWrapper&
for (auto& el : mywr) {
    //...
}

// this one won't compile
const MyWrapper& myconst = someConstMethod(); // returns const MyWrapper&
for (const auto& el : myconst) {
    //...
}
```

The error given is "no instance of function "MyWrapper::begin" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match) - object type is: const MyWrapper".

As this should be a pretty common use case, I'm sure there's a page specifying exactly which methods to implement to get this working, but I haven't been able to find it so far.

Comment: You're missing the const versions of begin and end. And no, I'm not talking about `cend` and `cbegin`.

Comment: `typename _Container::const_iterator begin () const noexcept` I assume? Was looking through the implementation of list and saw that these exist. Is there any page documenting them all and how are the used?

Comment: You missed the `const` versions. The range based for loops look for `begin` and `end` not `cbegin`/`cend`. You need `auto begin() const { return cbegin(); }`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end

Comment: methods needed: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: You need `const` versions of `begin()` and `end()`. Also, [`cbegin()` and `cend()` are useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134725/8584929), at least by some definitions of that word.

Comment: Why not inherit from the list class. Are you hiding some functionality of the list class?